# use autocomplete search bar with fetched api data react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to create an autocomplete drop-down search bar, which I found [Here](https://swairaq.medium.com/react-native-dropdown-searchbar-adc4532f7535) and I try to use it with populated data `dataSource` with worked well, but when I used it with my fetched data from an API it don't work see code below

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
    const [dataSource] = useState(['apple', 'banana', 'cow', 'dex', 'zee', 'orange', 'air', 'bottle'])
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(dataSource);
    const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
  
    const onSearch = (text) => {
        if (text) {
          setSearching(true)
  
          const temp = text.toLowerCase()
          const tempList = dataSource.filter(item => {if (item.match(temp))return item})
          setFiltered(tempList)
          
        } else {
          setSearching(false)
        }
    }
  
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  
          <TextInput 
              style={styles.textInput}
              placeholder="Search"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              onChangeText={onSearch}
          />
  
              { searching &&
                <SearchDropDown 
                  dataSource={filtered} 
                />
              }        
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

**SearchDropDown.js**

```
const SearchDropDown = (props) => {
    const {dataSource} = props;

    return (
        <View>

                        {
                            dataSource.map((item,index) => {
                                return (
                                    <View>
                                        <View key={index}>
                                            <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{item}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                )
                            })
                        }

        </View>
    )
}
```

This is my code I replaced `dataSource` with `artistData` which is fetching my data from my API

```
      const [artistData, setArtist] = useState([]);
      const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(artistData);
      const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(serveURL)
        .then((response) => setArtist(response.data))
        .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
      }, []);
    
      const onSearch = (text) => {
          if (text) {
            setSearching(true)
    
            const temp = text.toLowerCase()
            const tempList = artistData.filter(item => {if (item.match(temp))return item})
            setFiltered(tempList)
            
          } else {
            setSearching(false)
          }
      }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

        <TextInput 
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="Search"
            placeholderTextColor='white'
            onChangeText={onSearch}
        />

            { searching &&
              <SearchDropDown 
              artistData={filtered} 
              />
            }       

</SafeAreaView>
)
```

Also make the changes in `SearchDropDown.js` from `const {dataSource} = props;` and `dataSource.map` to this `const {artistData} = props;` and `artistData.map` but still did not work, I check the if there is data in `artistData` with `flatlist` see blow

```
  <FlatList 
                data = {serveURL}
                listKey="artist-data"
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                  return (
                      <Text>{item.artist_name}</Text>
                  )
                }}          
    />
```

It shows that there is data there, please I will need your help with this, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `yarn add react-native-autocomplete-dropdown` view complete Docs on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-dropdown

Example 
https://snack.expo.dev/@onmotion/react-native-autocomplete-dropdown

Comment: Thanks @rafiulah I know about `react-native-autocomplete-dropdown` but this code match exactly what I want to use it for.